# Unique Sort how to implement this

Tags: arrays, sorting

Rahul has found a new and unique way of sorting the arrays.

If the array is not sorted, he would remove the first or the second half of the array and he keeps on doing this process unless the array is completely sorted.

Your task is to find out the largest sorted array that can be obtained from the given unsorted array.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please review the basic tour and how to asp ask appropriate questions

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

```
  //write your code here
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int t = sc.nextInt();
  while(t-- > 0){
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(unique(arr, n));
  }
}
static int unique(int arr[], int n){
  boolean flag = true;
  int count = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
    if(arr[i] >arr[i+1])
      flag = false;
  }
  if(flag == true){
    return n;
  }
  else {
            int left = 0;
            int right = n - 1;
            int counter[] = new int[1];
            mergeSort(arr, left, right, counter);
            return counter[0]+1;
        }
  // return 1;
}static void mergeSort(int arr[], int left, int right, int counter[]) {
    if (left < right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, left, mid, counter);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, right, counter);
        merge(arr, left, mid, right, counter);
    }
}

static void merge(int arr[], int left, int mid, int right, int counter[]) {
    int n1 = mid - left + 1;
    int n2 = right - mid;
    int L[] = new int[n1];
    int R[] = new int[n2];

    for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
        L[i] = arr[left + i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        R[i] = arr[mid + i + 1];
    }

    int i = 0, j = 0, counter1 = 0;

    while (i < n1 - 1) {
        if (L[i] <= L[i + 1]) {
            i++;
            counter1++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (counter1 + 1 == n1) {
        if (counter1 > counter[0]) {
            counter[0] = counter1;
        }
    }

    int counter2 = 0;
    while (j < n2 - 1) {
        if (R[j] <= R[j + 1]) {
            j++;
            counter2++;
        
        } else {

            break;
        }

    }
    if(counter2+1 == n2) {
        if (counter2 > counter[0]) {
            counter[0] = counter2;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can just use the merge sort approach, not to sort the array but to find the sorted array by removing the first half and second half recursively. Here is the code, dry run it then you will get it.

```
  import java.util.*;
  import java.io.*;
  
  public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tc = sc.nextInt();
        while (tc-- > 0) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int arr[] = new int[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            boolean flag = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                if (arr[i] <= arr[i + 1]) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }

            if (flag) {
                System.out.println(n);
            } else {
                int left = 0;
                int right = n - 1;
                int counter[] = new int[1];
                mergeSort(arr, left, right, counter);
                System.out.println(counter[0]+1);
            }

        }
    }

    static void mergeSort(int arr[], int left, int right, int counter[]) {
        if (left < right) {
            int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
            mergeSort(arr, left, mid, counter);
            mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, right, counter);
            merge(arr, left, mid, right, counter);
        }
    }

    static void merge(int arr[], int left, int mid, int right, int counter[]) {
        int n1 = mid - left + 1;
        int n2 = right - mid;
        int L[] = new int[n1];
        int R[] = new int[n2];

        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            L[i] = arr[left + i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
            R[i] = arr[mid + i + 1];
        }

        int i = 0, j = 0, counter1 = 0;

        while (i < n1 - 1) {
            if (L[i] <= L[i + 1]) {
                i++;
                counter1++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (counter1 + 1 == n1) {
            if (counter1 > counter[0]) {
                counter[0] = counter1;
            }
        }

        int counter2 = 0;
        while (j < n2 - 1) {
            if (R[j] <= R[j + 1]) {
                j++;
                counter2++;
            
            } else {

                break;
            }

        }
        if(counter2+1 == n2) {
            if (counter2 > counter[0]) {
                counter[0] = counter2;
            }
        }
    }
  }
```